# Upgrading req.param to req.body changes method=POST to method=GET from twilio MediaURL

Tags: express, twilio

In my app.post file I have changed

```
var mediaUrl = req.param('MediaUrl' + i); //deprecated in express 4
```

to

```
var mediaUrl = req.body.MediaUrl + i; or req.params.MediaUrl + i;
```

viewing my console logs it does link to to twilio MediaURL0.  But on Heroko logs

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/message" host=(removed).herokuapp.com request_id=(removed)" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=95ms status=200 bytes=256 protocol=https
```

becomes

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/null" host=(removed).herokuapp.com request_id=(removed) fwd="74.3.132.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=146 protocol=https
```

When I upgraded.  What I am trying to figure out is why the MediaURL will become a Method=GET, yet any other information will stay as a Method=POST.  I require my MediaURL to be a Method=POST for my Twilio SMS messaging app to work.

Here is my complete app.post

```
app.post('/message', function (req, res) {
groupRef.where( {"memberNumber":req.body.From} ).limit(1).on( "value", function ( data ){
    if( data.count() ){
        data.forEach( function( snapshot ){
            var member = snapshot.value();
            messagesRef.push({
                sid: req.body.MessageSid,
                type:'text',
                tstamp: new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "America/Denver" }),
                fromName:member.memberName,
                fromNumber:req.body.From,
                message:req.body.Body,
                media:"",
                groupNumber:req.body.To
            });
        });
    }
});

var numMedia = parseInt( req.body.NumMedia );
if (numMedia > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < numMedia; i++) {
        //var mediaUrl = req.body.MediaUrl + i;
        //var mediaUrl = req.params.MediaUrl + i;
        var mediaUrl = req.param('MediaUrl' + i); //deprecated in express 4
        groupRef.where( {"memberNumber":req.body.From} ).limit(1).on( "value", function ( data ){
            if( data.count() ){
                data.forEach( function( snapshot ){
                    var member = snapshot.value();
                    messagesRef.push({
                        sid: req.body.MessageSid,
                        type:'text',
                        tstamp: new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "America/Denver" }),
                        fromName:member.memberName,
                        fromNumber:req.body.From,
                        message:"",
                        media:mediaUrl,
                        groupNumber:req.body.To
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
resp.message('Message received.');
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type':'text/xml'
});
res.end(resp.toString());
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to calculate an object property name you're going to have to use the bracket notation to access it.

```
var mediaUrl = req.body['MediaUrl' + i];
```

Comment: I am embarrassed to say I tried var mediaUrl = req.body.['MediaUrl' + i];  as soon as I can I will accept this answer.  Thanks for the Help